# Fade in EditText like the Notification Bar does?

Tags: android, android-edittext, uinavigationbar, swipe

I want to make a EditText visible from the bottom of my app like the notification bar does from the top. So if I swipe a bar (which can be shown all the time) from the bottom to the top, my EditText should be shown like in this picture:
[image]

Is there an easy way to program this? Or do you know a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this library can help you out: http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-swipeview/